# Cypher virtual nodes to aggregate many to many relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 8000 Authors nodes and 2000 book nodes. Each author has a country property and each book can be co-authored by many authors.

I am trying to show which countries have collaborated on books by grouping all authors from a country into a single virtualNode called Country. Then I would need to create a virtual relationship between countries based on the number of times each author in CountryA has published something with an Author from CountryB.

I have a few queries that are doing stuff, but can't get it quite to what I want. Here is what I have tried and the outcome:

```
MATCH (a1:Author)-->(p:Paper)<--(a2:Author)
WHERE a1.country <> a2.country
WITH apoc.create.vNode(['Country'], {name: a1.country}) as Country1,  apoc.create.vNode(['Country'], {name: a2.country}) as Country2, count(p) as numCollabs
RETURN DISTINCT Country1, Country2, apoc.create.vRelationship(Country1, 'COLLABORATED_WITH', {numCollabs: numCollabs}, Country2) LIMIT 25
```

This shows many duplicate countries ( I assume 1 for each author rather than aggregating authors ) and the numCollabs on each relationship is always 1.

I also tried this one:

```
MATCH (a: Author)
WITH a.country as country, count(*) as count
RETURN apoc.create.vNode(['Country'], {name: country, authors: count}) as countries
```

This gives me the proper number of countries and shows the number of authors in that country... however, I cannot figure out how to then create the vRelationship which will show how many times each country has worked with each other country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I tried to adapt the example [here](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/virtual/virtual-nodes-rels/) to your data.

```
MATCH (a:Author) 
WITH collect(distinct a.country) as countries
WITH [cName in countries | apoc.create.vNode(['Country'],{name:cName})] as countryNodes
WITH apoc.map.groupBy(countryNodes,'name') as countries
MATCH (a1:Author)-->(p:Paper)<--(a2:Author)
WHERE a1.country < a2.country
WITH a1.country AS countryName1, 
a2.country as countryName2, 
count(distinct p) as numCollabs, countries
RETURN countries[countryName1] as country1, 
countries[countryName2] as country2, 
apoc.create.vRelationship(countries[countryName1], 'COLLABORATED_WITH', {numCollabs: numCollabs}, countries[countryName2]) LIMIT 25
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Definitely closer. The answer above throws an error as numCollabs is not defined. Once I add num collabs back into the second WITH, I get a good result but the only issue now is that there are still multiple nodes for each country... i.e. I have one england node for every country england collaborated with (so 50+england nodes), rather than just one england node with rels going out to multiple countries. I'm sure I just need a Distinct in there somewhere, I just don't know where to put it lol.

Comment: Sorry about that! Edited to fix that problem.

Comment: Perfect thanks. Just needed to add "countries as countries" to last WITH to make it available in the RETURN. Otherwise will mark this as correct. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Good call. Edited in case future users need that.

Comment: Sorry to follow this up. I was wondering if this query can be modified to add other properties from the author node to the virtual node... for example, the author node also has latitude and longitude data. Can these be collected and added just like the country name? I've tried various ways of doing this, but no joy.

Comment: Are all of the latitudes and longitudes for an author the same, or do you need to average them?

Comment: They are the same for authors from the same countries.

Comment: were you able to find out if this was possible?